# How to remove "[Command was successful]" in VS Code Terminal for watchexec Script Execution?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I am experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code where I consistently receive a "[Command was successful]" message in the terminal after executing a JavaScript file using a Bash script with watchexec.

My script is simple:

```
watchexec --no-meta --exts js "clear; node script.js"
```

Whenever this script runs, the output in the VS Code terminal ends with:

```
Hello World!
[Command was successful]
```

I've tried:

1. Direct Execution in Terminal: Running node script.js directly in the terminal doesn't produce this message. It seems specific to the execution via the Bash script.
2. Reviewing settings.json: I've checked my VS Code settings for any configurations that might be related to this behavior but found nothing.
3. Altering the Bash Script: Attempted to filter out the message using grep -v within the script, but it had no effect.

How can I remove or suppress the "[Command was successful]" message in the VS Code terminal? This message appears to be linked to the use of watchexec in my script, but I'm not certain if it's an issue with watchexec, VS Code, or another part of my setup. I'm looking for a solution or workaround that can be easily integrated into my current workflow without extensive modifications.

Comment: jave you searched the source of `watchexec`, if it is in there you can recompile the Rust code, You can use it to define a separator for your `problemMatcher`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rust but I will have a look at watchexec repo to see if I can find the source of the message. Thank you